# Create servlet in Wicket to pass input as a parameter on submit to the web page

Tags: wicket

I'm new to Wicket and have made an application using some tutorials.

How do I create a servlet and pass on the input from that to a web page without database transactions?

Comment: what do you mean with 'input from that to webpage'? get the data from the servlet to show in a WicketPage? Or redirect from a servlet to a WicketPage with parameters?

Comment: @bert : i want to redirect from servlet with params to a WicketPage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you are trying redirect to a Wicket page (parameterized) from outside the Wicket application.

You can do this by using one of the URL encoding strategies (`BookmarkablePageRequestTargetUrlCodingStrategy`, `QueryStringUrlCodingStrategy`, ...) which will give that page a clean URL which can be referenced easily. Or you can put a `BookmarkablePageLink` in your web application somewhere, copy the link that it generates and use it to redirect to.

You can reference that link anywhere you wish passing parameters to it using the normal `?par1=val&par2=val` system.

To read these parameters in your page you will need to define your page constructor like so:

```
...
public MyPage(final PageParameters parameters) {
    final String par1 = parameters.getString("par1");
    final String par2 = parameters.getString("par2");
}
...
```